# What is the inverse $Z$-transform for $X(z) = \frac{5z}{3z-15}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-geometry, z-transform

I have been trying to figure out this for quite some time but my basic mathematical understanding does not want to co-operate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
X(z)=\frac53 \cdot \frac{1}{1-5\cdot z^{-1}}
$$ then using the linearity of the $Z$-transform and using a [table of common $Z$-transform pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Table_of_common_Z-transform_pairs) gives
$$
\frac53 \cdot5^n \: u[n]
$$ as being the signal, where
$$
u : n \mapsto u[n] = \begin{cases} 1, & n \ge 0 \\ 0, & n < 0 \end{cases}
$$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form).

Comment: Can you explain what happens to the 15? You first take the quotient ( 5/3) out and then eliminate z's to get ones.

Comment: I've written the denominator as $3z-15=3z \cdot \left(1-\frac{15}{3z}\right)=3z \cdot \left(1-5  z^{-1}\right)$ since $\frac{15}3=5$.